# Class member function works normally, but gets stuck in an infinite loop when called as a data member of another class

Tags: c++, loops, tree, infinite

I wrote a tree structure and made a basic search function to look for nodes within the tree. The tree itself uses a sentinel node to mark all ends (parent of the root, child of the leaves), and search simply iterates through nodes until it either finds a match or hits the sentinel node. The search function works fine when I call it on an instance of a tree, however it gets stuck when the tree is a data member of another class. In the following code, "t.search(1)" works, but "embedded_tree.t.search(1)" gets stuck in an infinite loop.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that when the call to embedded_tree.t.search() is made, the content of "&sentinel" correctly points to the sentinel node, but seems to be a new pointer, as it is not equivalent to the contents of root, sentinel.parent, and sentinel.child. From here I am stuck and am not sure how to call it so that &sentinel matches the pointers that were created when the tree was constructed.

```
#include <iostream>

struct NODE {
    int key;
    NODE* parent;
    NODE* child;
    NODE() : key(0), parent(NULL), child(NULL) {};
};

struct TREE {
    NODE sentinel;
    NODE* root;

    TREE()
    {
        sentinel = *new NODE;
        sentinel.parent = &sentinel;
        sentinel.child = &sentinel;
        root = &sentinel;
    }

    NODE* search(int k)
    {
        NODE* x = root;
        while (x != &sentinel)
        {
            if (x->key == k) return x;
            x = x->child;
        }
        return &sentinel;
    }
};

struct A {
    TREE t;

    A() : t(*new TREE()) {};
};

int main()
{
    TREE t;
    t.search(1);

    A embedded_tree;
    embedded_tree.t.search(1);
}
```

Comment: `sentinel = *new NODE;` is not a good idea.

Comment: `t(*new TREE())` -- Why are you doing this? You don't use `new` unless you're assigning to a pointer and you don't use it unless you need to (hint: it's not necessary here and causes a memory leak).

Comment: What does your debugger tell you when you trace the `embedded_tree.t.search(1);` function call?

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, what would be the recommended way to create the sentinel and the A.t member here?

Comment: My debugger doesn't say anything as far as I can tell, when I trace it it just loops infinitely at while (x != &sentinel) because the two will never be equivalent. However, this does not occur when it is just called as t.search(1);

Comment: @Brodie FYI, you need to use @ or your response will not notify the person. For a stack based object `TREE t;` alone is sufficient (just like you've done in `main`). You didn't seem compelled to do `TREE t = *new TREE();` in main so why are you doing it that way in multiple other places?

Comment: @JamesAdkison For some reason I thought that declaring data members within a class definition wasn't the same as calling them in main where they would use the default constructor. I removed the lines using *new everywhere I had them and it works! I still have no idea what changed behind the scenes, but it seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing dynamic memory allocation with stack allocation. When you do

```
sentinel = *new NODE
```

bad things happen. Memory gets allocated for `NODE sentinel` on the stack, then for `NODE` in `new` operator, then assignment gets done to `sentinel` variable, and memory created in `new` operator is lost. You should rewrite your code to use pointers instead, and add destructors, something like this

```
#include <iostream>

struct NODE {
    int key;
    NODE* parent;
    NODE* child;
    NODE() : key(0), parent(NULL), child(NULL) {};
};

struct TREE {
    NODE* sentinel;
    NODE* root;

    TREE()
    {
        sentinel = new NODE;
        sentinel->parent = sentinel;
        sentinel->child = sentinel;
        root = sentinel;
    }

    ~TREE() {
        if (NULL != sentinel) {
            delete sentinel;
            sentinel = NULL;
            root = NULL;
        }
    }

    NODE* search(int k)
    {
        NODE* x = root;
        while (x != sentinel)
        {
            if (x->key == k) return x;
            x = x->child;
        }
        return sentinel;
    }


};

struct A {
    TREE* t;

    A() : t(new TREE()) {};
    ~A() {
        if (NULL != t) {
            delete t;
            t = NULL;
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
    TREE t;
    t.search(1);

    A embedded_tree;
    embedded_tree.t->search(1);
}
```

However, since we're talking about C++, I'd suggest you to look to smart pointers and containers after you get familiar with manual memory management.